# Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" should have required property 'browserTarget'. ng serve ( Angular 11)

Tags: angular

`$ ng serve gives the following error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" should have required property 'browserTarget'.`

Just upgraded to V11.  ng build is successful.
I've spent a number of hours trying but always getting the same result.
Have tried:

1. remove package-lock.json and node_modules
2. npm i
3. ng build
4. ng serve
   and always have the error.
   `

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "GRIDDASH",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --aot",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "11.2.14",
    "@cds/core": "5.0.0",
    "@clr/angular": "5.5.3",
    "@clr/icons": "12.0.12",
    "@clr/ui": "5.5.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "16.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "19.0.0",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "1.0.8",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.19",
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "0.1102.19",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "11.2.19",
    "@angular/cli": "11.2.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/localize": "11.2.14",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "11.2.14",
    "@types/node": "17.0.31",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.1",
    "ts-node": "4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.8",
    "webpack": "4.46.0",
    "d3": "4.12.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "karma": "6.3.19"
  }
```

angular.json "serve"stanza:

```
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-springboot:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-springboot:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
```

This is kind of standard.

Comment: Upgraded to Angular 11 from what? Did you follow the migration guide for the version bump?

Comment: Upgrade all the way from 5 to 12.  But settle at v11 because one of the library, @swimlane/ngx-datatable,  it's latest version is not compatible with Angular v12.

Comment: BTW, I did followed the the guide, "https://update.angular.io/". Going from v5 to v6, I need to make a fair amount of coding changes to go with the rxjs pipe way of handling filter and map, mergemap etc.

Comment: Can you include the "serve" stanza from your angular.json?

Comment: Added "serve" stanza.

Comment: rebuild everything from scratch and this error is not showing up anymore. Can 'ng build' and then 'ng serve' and listening to 4200 port.  But it failed with the folowing error:``` core.js:1141 Uncaught Error: Type DecoratorFactory does not have 'ɵmod' property.
    at getNgModuleDef (core.js:1141:15)``` Going to raise another question.

Comment: If all else fails, using `npx @angular/cli@11 new my-app` to generate an Angular 11 (or whatever version instead of 11) project, then copying/diffing the relevant parts of the angular.json file to figure out the missing piece may help.